# Google Maps API v3: Custom Style for Terrain Maps

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone know if it is possible to create custom relief styles for Terrain maps? You can obviously create custom styles for normal maps but I would like to change the default colour ramps for terrain too,

Many thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can indeed style terrain maps. I have a JSFiddle here demonstrating this:

https://jsfiddle.net/w77bycw0/

In my sample I just turned bodies of water white just to demonstrate that you can style a terrain map. Please note that you will need to add your own API key for it to work!

The way you can style a terrain map is about the same way you style the road map, you just specify terrain map:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945},
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: 'terrain',
styles: [

  {
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{color: '#FFFFFF'}]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
    stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
  }
]
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: In the lower right pane I am getting "Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details."  Is this an error in my browser or has something changed?

Comment: It's been a couple years since I did support for Google maps, so I can't guarantee things work the same way. However, I believe the reason you are getting that error is because you need to include your API key in the request. I redacted my API key from the jsfiddle for security purposes, as API keys are meant to be private. If you get your own key and insert it in the fiddle where it says "MY_API_KEY" you should be able to load the map properly.