# google mapView styling doesn't work on Android with maptype=TERRAIN

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, styling, android-maps-v2

Using this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430844/google-maps-api-v3-custom-style-for-terrain-maps), I have tried to apply some custom styling to an Android mapview.

The styling is basicly just making the water black

mapstyle_json.js:

```
[
    {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [{color: '#000000'}]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'water',
        elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
        stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
      }
]
```

My main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        final android.content.Context context = this;

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN); // Without this line, the styling works as intended
                try {
                    // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
                    // in a raw resource file.
                    boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                            MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                                    context, R.raw.mapstyle_json));

                    if (!success) {
                        Log.e("1", "Style parsing failed.");
                    }
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("1", "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
                }
                Log.d("1", "onMapReady: something");
                LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(45.832119, 6.865575);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title("hello"));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 12));
                mapView.onResume();
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

Without setting the map type (using the default map type), styling works as it should. It should be possible to style a TERRAIN type map, given the linked question. (Maybe only with javascript).

Why doesn't this styling get applied to a terrain type map? Is it possible in the Android mapView?

EDIT:

The code is based on google's own guide, with the raw resource use case: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling

Maybe this is a google API v2 vs v3 issue. As far as I understand, Android uses API v2. The linked issue is about v3

Answer (score 3):

Seems its expected behavior. From [Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling):

> Styling works only on the `normal` map type.

[Normal map type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_types) is:

> Typical road map. Shows roads, some features built by humans, and
>   important natural features like rivers. Road and feature labels are
>   also visible.

Comment: It says it like it doesn't work on indoor maps: **Styling works only on the normal map type. Styling does not affect indoor maps.** What could be a possible workaround? I am thinking something in the lines of creating a javascript view inside my android app

Comment: @JonasPraem No. "Styling does not affect indoor maps." - other sentence (but I agree - they can wrote it in better maner). Indoor maps is not map type (that can be `Normal`, `Hybrid`, `Satellite`, `Terrain` and `None`).

Comment: @JonasPraem And IMHO best workaround is to use [`Tile Overlay`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay) that loads `normal` map tile from Google URLs (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241268/how-to-get-your-image-url-tiles-google-maps) question) and set water to black (and other to transparent) on tile bitmap directly.

Comment: It is possible on a javascript map (see linked issue), which is why this frustrates me. I was also thinking of an opacity overlay, say i just want the whole map more redish - and add an opacity color on top. Maybe doing a javascript view inside my Android application - maybe that is possible for the mapview?

Comment: @JonasPraem I think everything is possible, but IMHO best workaround is to use Tile Overlay that loads normal map tile... )

Comment: I think the Tile Overlay is a good option. The accepted answer should probably include that